# Modify Post Excerpts

Tags: wordpress

I am using a wordpress install with the Advanced Excerpt plugin. I have changed the settings so that no text is displayed in excerpt, but I cant get it to remove the category and tag labels aswell.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information about 1) your code and 2) the solutions that you have tried but are not working as you expected it to.

Comment: I have looked into my theme files, I check the page-archive.php and function.php and have not found anything that could stop this from appearing. The Advanced Excerpt plugin doesn't have a feature to exclude this either...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by inserting the following code into stylesheet.css;

```
.archive-excerpt {
display: none;
}
```